# Entire function of exponential type zero is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying some complex analysis by myself and I'm stuck in the following problem:
Let $F:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function of exponential type zero such that $F^{(k)}\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for some $1\leq p\leq \infty$ and some $k\geq 0$. Prove that $F$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$.

I don't know how to start solving such problem (I've been thinking about it a lot), so I would be grateful if someone can give me some hint or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use Bernstein's inequality together with:

**Hint:** if entire $F$ is exponential type $\tau$, then so is $F'$.

Comment: The inequality that I know (wich is related to Bernstein inequality I guess) state that a entire function $f$ of exponential type $\delta$ wich is bounded on the real axis satisfies $||f'||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\leq \delta ||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}$. In this case, with ur hint I think that one can deduce that $F',\cdots, F^{(k)}$ are of exponential type $\delta$, and then applying such estimate and taking $\delta\to 0$ (bcs the zero exp type) the result follows. However, such $F^{(k+1)}$ not necessarily is bounded on the real axis, or I'm missing something?

Comment: You don't need the boundedness condition to conclude $\lVert f'\rVert\leq\delta\lVert f\rVert$.  In fact Plancherel and Polya proved that for entire $f$, if $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ ($p\geq 1$) then $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ so $f$ is bounded on the real axis.

Comment: I see, such conclusion follows from the Plancherel-Pólya inequality with the sequence $(n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ (I knew that result, my bad). Then I can apply it for $F^{(k)}$ followed by $|| F^{(k+1)} ||\leq \delta || F^{(k)}||$ to get that $F^{(n)}$ is zero for $n\geq k+1$. Thank you very much for your help!